# Highscore file function for Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: c

So I'm a C beginner and I'm writing a Tic Tac Toe game in C for class. The game works fine so far but I'm trying to include a file that keeps track of the player's stats (i.e. wins, losses, ties, etc.). I'm trying to write a loop that takes the values from the file and writes them into a global array or prints all zeros into the file if the file is empty (i.e. it's the player's first game). I've tried this loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if (fscanf(fptr, "%d", statistics_p1[i]) != 1) {
            fprintf(fptr, "%d ", statistics_p1[i]);
        } else {
            fscanf(fptr, "%d", statistics_p1[i]);
        }
    }
```

But the array always remains filled with all zeros, even if the file already contains data. What can I do?

Comment: You need `&` with `scanf`. You should also pay attention to compiler warnings.

Comment: I don't follow the if-else logic in the snippet. If `fscanf` fails, you print the original value that wasn't replaced. But if it succeeds, you overwrite the value you just read successfully with another (subject to the missing `&)`. Are you sure about what `scanf` functions return? It is the number of successful conversions made, or `EOF`.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also include the contents of your file, or a minimal version of the code that generates it.

Comment: why a `fscanf` into the else part ?